# why is my program using system cpu time?

Tags: python, fortran, profiling, cpu-usage, lapack

I wrote a time-consuming python program. Basically, the python program spends most of its time in a fortran routine wrapped by `f2py` and the fortran routine spends most of its time in lapack. However, when I ran this program in my workstation, I found 80% of the cpu time was user time and 20% of cpu time was system time.

In another SO question, I Read:

> The difference is whether the time is spent in user space or kernel space. User CPU time is time spent on the processor running your program's code (or code in libraries); system CPU time is the time spent running code in the operating system kernel on behalf of your program.

So if this is true, I assume all the cpu time should be devoted to user time. Does 20% percent system time indicate I need to profile the program?

**EDIT:**

More information: I cannot reproduce the 20% percent system cpu time. In another run, the `time` command gives:

- real  5m14.804s
- user  78m6.233s
- sys   4m53.896s

Comment: Can you give the actual time spent in user/kernel space for some runs? Although the percentage are helpfull, they really make more sense only for long runs where the startup time is negligible.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @AlexanderVogt, which part of the program do you need? The python part, the fortran part? The code is too long to be pasted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operating systems are constantly switching out what is running at any given moment. Your program will run for a while, but eventually there will be an interrupt, and the system will switch to something else, or it may just decide to run something else for a second or two, then switch back. It is difficult to force an operating system not to do this behavior. That's part of the job of the OS; keeping things moving in all areas.